# using jbehave to export stories to html

Tags: bdd, jbehave, jbehave-plugin

I have a directory tree organised with stories, where stories are grouped by their functional responsibilities, e.g.

```
C:\specifications
   |
   + myproject
     |
     |- admin stories
     |  |- account_management.story
     |  +- finance_management.story
     |
     +- customer stories
        |- pay_bils.story 
        +- update_details.story
```

There are hundreds of features and stories, so it's difficult to get a high level view of the functionality.

**Question:** Does JBehave enable you to convert the text based stories into a more readable format, such as a HTML document that enables you to drill down into the detail, or zoom back up to just see the feature and story titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jbehave-to-gherkin](https://github.com/adaptive-logic/jbehave-to-gherkin) project can be used to export stories to gherkin format.

After that, the gherkin features can be processed with [pickles](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles) to create some really nice html output.