# how to run jbehave stories without mapping classes so that I can produce html output?

Tags: jbehave

I would like to produce html output of my stories. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187880/using-jbehave-to-export-stories-to-html) for more information.

I have been informed that it is possible to run jbehave stories without mapping classes to produce html output.  However, I can't find any documentation on the jbehave site for running stories without mapping classes.

**Question**: How can I run jbehave on my stories without having any mapping classes so that I can product html ouput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used this [project](https://github.com/adaptive-logic/jbehave-to-gherkin) which successfully exported my stories to gherkin format.

After that, I processed them using this [project](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles) to create some really nice html output.